# foreach loop not returning the correct data usign a function within a function

Tags: php, wordpress

folks, I can't get this to work. What I'm trying to do is to calculate the distance between latitude/longitude pairs, using a function.
I'm retrieving the data from my wordpress db table.
All is ok up to this point.
The problem I'm facing is that the first item retrieved from database calculates the distance perfectly, but all the others get repeated the same wrong value.
I'm trying to generate a json response for my api.

Here's the function to calculate the distance:

```
 function get_distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
 
  return ($miles * 1.609344);
            

}

Here's the function that retrieves data from db and calls get_distance() to calculate:

    function listing_by_coordinates($city){
    
        $cat = array();

            $ucat = array(
        'post_type' => 'listar',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'listar_category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $city,
            )
         )
        );

         
    $postID;
     
    $features = get_posts($ucat);
         
    $postID;
     
    $myresult = [];
    $i = 0;
    $dist = 0;

    foreach($features as $feature) {

    $postID = $feature->ID;
    
    $lat2 = get_field('latitude', $postID);
    $lon2 = get_field('longitude', $postID);
        
    $dist = get_distance('-25.440766549426275','-49.27733841639869',$lat2,$lon2);
        
    $cat[$i]['name'] = $feature->post_title;
    $cat[$i]['latitude'] = $lat2;
    $cat[$i]['longitude'] = $lon2; 
    $cat[$i]['distance'] = $dist;
                    
        $myresult[$i]=$cat;
        $i ++;
    
 } 
    return $cat;
        
    }
```

AND HERE IS THE RESULT. Note that the first entry has a correct distance, but all the rest gets the same wrong value.

```
  {
    "name": "PIZZAPP Batel",
    "latitude": "-25.44089532023346",
    "longitude": "-49.27379207908012",
    "distance": 0.356366447483585979671971699644927866756916046142578125
  },
  {
    "name": "yummizza",
    "latitude": "-25,433287",
    "longitude": "-49,272498",
    "distance": 56.39252784156145281713179429061710834503173828125
  },
  {
    "name": "Zak Pizzas",
    "latitude": "-25,480155",
    "longitude": "-49,335803",
    "distance": 56.39252784156145281713179429061710834503173828125
  },
  {
    "name": "Zap Pizzaria",
    "latitude": "-25,379378",
    "longitude": "-49,254974",
    "distance": 56.39252784156145281713179429061710834503173828125
  },
  {
    "name": "Zap Pizzaria Água Verde",
    "latitude": "-25,461179",
    "longitude": "-49,294455",
    "distance": 56.39252784156145281713179429061710834503173828125
  },
  {
    "name": "Ziza Pizza",
    "latitude": "-25,517236",
    "longitude": "-49,295935",
    "distance": 56.39252784156145281713179429061710834503173828125
  },
  {
    "name": "Zupt Sabor Pizza Burger Grill",
    "latitude": "-25,397456",
    "longitude": "-49,270823",
    "distance": 56.39252784156145281713179429061710834503173828125
  },
  {
    "name": "XBom Lanches",
    "latitude": "-25,434282",
    "longitude": "-49,276825",
    "distance": 56.39252784156145281713179429061710834503173828125
  },
  {
    "name": "Yankees Pizzaria",
    "latitude": "-25,460863",
    "longitude": "-49,201307",
    "distance": 56.39252784156145281713179429061710834503173828125
  },
  {
    "name": "Yellow Pizzaria",
    "latitude": "-25,475251",
    "longitude": "-49,296798",
    "distance": 56.39252784156145281713179429061710834503173828125
  }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

This is causing because the first entry has a correct longitude and latitude, but all the rest have comma instead of decimal point in the values of longitudes and latitudes. Like the second json value **"latitude" is "-25,433287" should be "-25.433287" and "longitude" is "-49,272498" should be "-49.272498"**. Same goes for the rest of the values.

```
{
    "name": "PIZZAPP Batel",
    "latitude": "-25.44089532023346",
    "longitude": "-49.27379207908012",
    "distance": 0.356366447483585979671971699644927866756916046142578125
  },
  {
    "name": "yummizza",
    "latitude": "-25,433287", //should be "-25.433287"
    "longitude": "-49,272498", //should be "-49.272498"
    "distance": 56.39252784156145281713179429061710834503173828125
  },
```

Comment: Yes, THANK YOU!!!